# Display Multidimensional Array of Custom Options from order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, custom-options, export

I created a script to export order information into a CSV but I'm unsure on how to display the contents of the array. What I'm trying to do is capture the custom options selected for a given order and display them. I'm new to PHP so having a hard time with this. So far I was able to display just the last option from each order but not all with this...

```
$_options = $block->getItemOptions();
     foreach ($_options as $option) {
         $str = $option['label'] . ' : ' . $option['value'];

     }
```

I then stored the value of $option into an array which when checking $array the output does contain all the selected options. I'm just unsure on how to extract the label & value of each custom option from an order to display in CSV. The below code doesn't work!

```
$_options = $block->getItemOptions();
     foreach ($_options as $option) {
         $array[] = $option;
         $str = $array['label'] . ' : ' . $array['value'];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you are just overwriting what content was already contained in the variable `$str`. You want to append to that variable instead.

```
$str = ''; // initialize variable as a string
foreach($_options as $option){
    $str .= $option['label'] . ': ' . $option['value'] . ' // ';
}
echo $str;
```

The above is a simplistic example, but it's what you want to do.